# How can I check JavaScript arrays for empty strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check if array contains at least one empty elements. If any of the one element is empty then it will return false.

Example:

```
var my_arr = new Array(); 
my_arr[0] = ""; 
my_arr[1] = " hi ";
my_arr[2] = "";
```

The 0th and 2nd array elements are "empty".

Comment: By empty do you mean `undefined` or empty strings?

Comment: var my_arr = new Array();
my_arr[0] = "";
my_arr[1] = " hi ";
my_arr[2] = "";
here the 0th and 2nd element is empty

Comment: Is this a Java question or a javascript question? These are completely unrelated. Oh, and now it looks like PHP with all those $ signs. Make up your mind...

Comment: santanu, The code you just posted is PHP. Not JavaScript.

Comment: @santanu: I converted your code to JavaScript and added it to your question.

Comment: yes i have done this thing in php, thus provided the code from php, I stucked on doin this in java script

Comment: @Johannes: It's valid Javascript code too, some libraries use it as a sort of hungarian notation to denote specific kinds of variables.

Comment: @Michael: It began with `$my_arr = array();`.  *array()* isn't defined in ECMAScript/JavaScript, unless you define it yourself.  *array()* is a PHP constructor for arrays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to check in through loop.

```
function checkArray(my_arr){
   for(var i=0;i<my_arr.length;i++){
       if(my_arr[i] === "")   
          return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

You can check by looping through the array with a simple `for`, like this:

```
function NoneEmpty(arr) {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] === "") return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/G8mmj/3/), the reason we're not using `.indexOf()` here is lack of support in IE, otherwise it'd be even simpler like this:

```
function NoneEmpty(arr) {
  return arr.indexOf("") === -1;
}
```

But alas, IE doesn't support this function on arrays, at least not yet.

Comment: Isn't this the reverse of what the OP asked for (returns true if the array  has only empty elements, instead of returns false if any element is empty)?

Comment: Good call on the indexOf for array's. Now just let's hope someone from the IE dev team reads this and fix it !

Comment: @Telemachus - Good catch, I missed his explicit "which result is false" requirement, updated :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if we make `isEmpty` function the second parameter of `HasEmpty`, and the `arr[i] === ""` implementation as default.

Comment: FWIW, which probably isn't much until we can drop support for <IE8, IE9 will support *indexOf()* and the other ECMAScript 5th array functions. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/25/enhanced-scripting-in-ie9-ecmascript-5-support-and-more.aspx

Comment: You could still use `indexOf` where it exists: `var arrayHasEmpty = Array.prototype.indexOf ? function(arr) { return arr.indexOf("") != -1; } : function(arr) { /* for loop stuff here */ };`

Answer (score 8):

You can try [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function:

```
return jQuery.inArray("", my_arr)
```

Comment: Including jQuery for this seems *just* a bit overkill, don'tcha think?

Comment: @Nick Craver - yes, overkill if this is the only reason for using jQuery. On the other hand, when using jQuery this is a good solution :-)

Comment: @Vitalii - *Sometimes* it's used, it's still a minority, my point was you should qualify this type of answer on a question not tagged jQuery with something like "If you're already using jQuery..."  A novice finding this later and including jQuery for *just* this would be a bad thing.

Comment: @Vitalii - I think you misunderstood, I meant a JS novice, not an SO one.  By definition, they don't know what's best :)

Answer (score 5):

Using a ["higher order function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) like [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of looping can sometimes make for faster, safer, and more readable code. Here, you could filter the array to remove items that are *not* the empty string, then check the length of the resultant array.

**Basic JavaScript**

```js
var my_arr = ["", "hi", ""]

// only keep items that are the empty string
new_arr = my_arr.filter(function(item) {
  return item === ""
})

// if filtered array is not empty, there are empty strings
console.log(new_arr);
console.log(new_arr.length === 0);
```

**Modern Javascript: One-liner**

```js
var my_arr = ["", "hi", ""]
var result = my_arr.filter(item => item === "").length === 0
console.log(result);
```

**A note about performance**

Looping is likely faster in this case, since you can stop looping as soon as you find an empty string. I might still choose to use `filter` for code succinctness and readability, but either strategy is defensible.

If you needed to loop over all the elements in the array, however-- perhaps to check if *every* item is the empty string-- filter would likely be much faster than a for loop!

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays we can use [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
my_arr.includes("")
```

Returns a Boolean

Answer (score 3):

You could do a simple help method for this:

```
function hasEmptyValues(ary) {
    var l = ary.length,
        i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
        if (!ary[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//check for empty
var isEmpty = hasEmptyValues(myArray);
```

EDIT: This checks for `false`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `null`, `""` and `0`.

EDIT2: Misread the true/false expectation.

..fredrik

Answer (score 3):

```
function containsEmpty(a) {
    return [].concat(a).sort().reverse().pop() === "";
}
alert(containsEmpty(['1','','qwerty','100'])); // true
alert(containsEmpty(['1','2','qwerty','100'])); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my_arr.includes("")
```

This returned **undefined** instead of a boolean value so here's an **alternative**.

```js
function checkEmptyString(item){
     if (item.trim().length > 0) return false;
     else return true;
    };
    
function checkIfArrayContainsEmptyString(array) {
  const containsEmptyString = array.some(checkEmptyString);
  return containsEmptyString;
};
    
console.log(checkIfArrayContainsEmptyString(["","hey","","this","is","my","solution"]))
// *returns true*

console.log(checkIfArrayContainsEmptyString(["yay","it","works"]))
// *returns false*
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yourArray.join('').length > 0
```

Join your array without any space in between and check for its length. If the length, turns out to be greater than zero that means array was not empty. If length is less than or equal to zero, then array was empty.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I see in your comments beneath the question that the code example you give is PHP, so I was wondering if you were actually going for the PHP one? In PHP it would be:

```
function hasEmpty($array)
{
  foreach($array as $bit)
  {
    if(empty($bit)) return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Otherwise if you actually did need JavaScript, I refer to Nick Craver's answer

Answer (score 1):

Just do a  `len(my_arr[i]) == 0;`  inside a loop to check if string is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check in through the array of some functions.

if `isEmptyValue` is true that means the array has an empty string otherwise not.

```js
const arr=['A','B','','D'];

const isEmptyValue = arr.some(item => item.trim() === '');

console.log(isEmptyValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const hasEmptyString = (arr) => arr.includes('');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var containsEmpty = !my_arr.some(function(e){return (!e || 0 === e.length);});
```

This checks for 0, false, undefined, "" and NaN.
It's also a one liner and works for IE 9 and greater.

Answer (score 0):

**One line solution to check if string have empty element**

```
let emptyStrings = strArray.filter(str => str.trim().length <= 0);
```

```js
let strArray = ['str1', '', 'str2', ' ', 'str3', '    ']
let emptyStrings = strArray.filter(str => str.trim().length <= 0);
console.log(emptyStrings)
```

**One line solution to get non-empty strings from an array**

```
let nonEmptyStrings = strArray.filter(str => str.trim().length > 0);
```

```js
let strArray = ['str1', '', 'str2', ' ', 'str3', '    ']
let nonEmptyStrings = strArray.filter(str => str.trim().length > 0);
console.log(nonEmptyStrings)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about empty strings then this will do it:

```
const arr = ["hi","hello","","jj"]
('' in arr) //returns false
```

the last line checks if an empty string was found in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most performant way, but here's a one liner in ES2015+:

```
// true if not empty strings
// false if there are empty strings
my_arr.filter(x => x).length === my_arr.length
```

The `.filter(x => x)` will return all the elements of the array that are not empty nor undefined. You then compare the length of the original array. If they are different, that means that the array contains empty strings.

Answer (score -2):

array.includes("") works just fine.

Let a = ["content1", "" , "content2"];
console.log(a.includes(""));

//Output in console
true

Comment: This solution has already been posted:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63144056/2227743