# Checking for an empty string array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to check for an empty string array like this:

```
var array = ['',''];
//Other code
if (array == ['',''])
    //Do stuff
```

and I've found that

```
['',''] == ['','']
```

returns `false`. Why is that? What method should I use to check for an empty string array? Is there a way where I don't have to check each individual item?

Comment: just checking or compairing with another array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check JavaScript arrays for empty strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457807/how-can-i-check-javascript-arrays-for-empty-strings)

Comment: Are you checking for a single element having empty string as value?

Comment: @NinaScholz The empty array I'm comparing against is always constant. Basically, I want to see if `array` contains only empty strings

Comment: @guest271314 I would like to check the whole array at once (if this is possible in JavaScript) rather than creating another loop to check each item, one at a time

Comment: `!array.every(item => item.length)`

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm using Google Apps Script and I don't believe I can use LINQ there

Comment: It's not LINQ, it's JavaScript (technically, ECMAScript 2015).

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Well, it throws an error in Google Apps Script: http://i.imgur.com/ZpKdbQQ.png

Comment: @derekantrican Umm, how can you check if every element is an empty string without checking every element, one way or another?

Comment: @torazaburo `array.toString() === ","`

Comment: @guest271314 Ah, that works!

Comment: Oh, DumbScript, sorry. `!array.every(function (item) { return item.length; });`

Comment: Is `array` the actual array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside the proposed using of [`Array#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method, I suggest to use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with an empty string as separator and then test the result. The advantage is, it works for an arbitrary count of elements inside of the array.

```
var bool = array.join('') ? 'not all empty string' : 'all empty string';
```

Comment: Nice one. Hadn't thought of using `join`.

Answer (score 2):

`['', ''] == ['', '']` returns `false` because in JavaScript arrays are objects, and objects in JavaScript have reference semantics. Comparing objects to each other actually compares their reference IDs, which will be different for different references. So, even though both sides of `==` are the "same" array, they are different references.

If you want to check that an array only contains empty strings, use `Array.prototype.every` as in the following:

```js
myArray = ['']
console.log(myArray.every(el => el === '')) // true
myArray = []
console.log(myArray.every(el => el === '')) // true
myArray = ['test']
console.log(myArray.every(el => el === '')) // false
```

If you are in an environment without ES6 support, you can swap the `el => el === ''` for `function(el) { return el === '' }`.

Comment: I am using Google Apps Script and this doesn't seem to work there: http://i.imgur.com/CLteUor.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
var arr = ["","", ""].reduce(function (a, b) {
  return a + b;
});

if(arr == "") {
console.log('Array is empty');
}
```

Comment: Your `reduce` is just a clumsy way to write `join`. Your code also won't work if the input array has no elements.

Comment: @torazaburo Point taken but the OP, didn't talk about empty array,, in the sense that array has no elements. What is your suggestion to make it better?

Comment: `var arr = ["", "", ""].join('');`.

Comment: My idea was towards reducing the array to single element,which what join() is doing here. Also, there are some studies that have been done that suggest that in modern browsers string concatenation is much faster than join() method. Hence I chose reduce(), which is doing string concatenation. These threads have such discussions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299010/why-is-string-concatenation-faster-than-array-join                                                         Another one, not exactly same but similar from Kyle Simpson, not so long ago https://davidwalsh.name/combining-js-arrays

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
var arr = [""];
console.log(String.valueOf(arr[0]) === String.valueOf(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Nina above this should also work!

```js
 let arr1 = ['']
 const bool1 = !!arr1.join(''); // false
 console.log(bool1)
            
 let arr2 = ['String']
 const bool2 = !!arr2.join(''); // true
 console.log(bool2)
```